# PHP Getting select query output as array

Tags: php, mysql

I've a select query say

```
 $query = "select name from class";
 $equery = mysql_query($query);
 $v = mysql_fetch_array($equery);    
 print_r($v['name']);
```

I've 10 records in my data base but always i'm getting only one value.is there any alternative to retrieve my column in array format.

Comment: Using `mysql_query` is probably a very bad idea as it's very hard to use correctly. Is there any reason you're not using `mysqli` or PDO?

Comment: Dont you have to loop through results to print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop it.

```
$query = "select name from class";
$equery = mysql_query($query);
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($equery)) {
    $result[] = $row['name'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `mysql` extension, as [it has been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).
You should use [`mysqli_result::fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) with the [`mysqli` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), or [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) with the [`PDO` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in a **LOOP**:

```
<?php

  while($v = mysql_fetch_array($equery);) {
  print_r($v['name']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "select name from class";
 $equery = mysql_query($query);

 $v=null;
 $index=0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($equery,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
     $v[$index++]=$row;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers which are correct: You shouldn't really be using any of the old `mysql` commands as they are being depreciated. You should check out `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't essentially need to loop it, if you have only one row in output, this way is fine, but if you have more, you need to loop.

```
$a=mysql_fetch_array($resource)
```

returns the first row,
loop it

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
{
echo ($row['name']);
}
```

mysql_fetch_assoc returns output in form of associative array. i keep saying this on all mysql posts, try switching to PDO.
**USE of mysql_query is discouraged.** It means it's support may soon be removed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: It's not only discouraged, it's finally in the first stages of the long-awaited deprecation process :), it might even be at the stage of issuing warnings with `E_STRICT | E_ALL` set...